# Can an individual do both Mincha and Maariv before dark on the same day?

Tags: zemanim, maariv, mincha-afternoon-prayer

It is commonly said one cannot daven both Mincha and Maariv before dark, 
on account that after Pelag haMinchah there is a dispute in the Gemara if it is time for this or for that [clarification needed | please cite].

But can one in fact do this? That is, can and individual daven both Mincha and Maariv, afer Pelag, before dark or even before Sheki`ah?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Nissim. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Why would anyone ever need to do this? If there's no set Minyan times one can just pray whenever. Is he that bad at scheduling that he couldn't plan ahead to not get stuck in the one hour a day that's a problem? Anyway he has to say Shema later so just pray Arvit then too.

Comment: I recall asking a related question about a congregation doing this - davening mincha "late" (after plag, I think) and Ma'ariv "early" before tzet. This is a problem as you cannot apply both definitions simultaneously. I'll see if I can locate that Q and post a link.

Comment: @Double_AA - why well how about erev shabat. And other times maybe just in the mood or convenience.  He cited there is a Tanna in the Gemara who did motzaei Shabbat arvit on Shabbat afternoon!  Can anyone confirm this w citation. Point about shema later well taken.  Btw does the first tosefta in gemara Shabbat say one fulfills shema after plag?

Comment: @nissim I don't understand how Erev Shabbat is a reason?

Comment: @Double_AA Say a minyan is not feasible, shkiah is 7PM, it's now 6:30 and you want to daven Mincha and Maariv to be maqabel Shabbath.  Aren't there many who say an individual cannot daven both in this "problem hour?"

Answer (score 2):

From SA"OC #235 it appears initially one should not do so, and that only a minyan can daven Ma`ariv early so as to not encumber them to assemble again if they had just done a late Minchah (i.e. after Pelag.).

My rav didn't have time to elaborate when I asked him but only said:

> No problem doing both after plag.

I looked up in Yalkuth Yossef and he writes concerning this:

> ...ve gam bazeh kevar nahagu lehaqel, veyesh lahem `al mah sheyismokhu.
>   Translation: But even this, the custom has already been to be lenient; and they have what to rely on.

There is a long footnote there from Yechaweh Da`ath; seems to me the following is the essence:

> ...ולדעת חכמים זמן תפלת מנחה עד הערב, ולא הוצרכו בגמרא להשמיענו אלא שיכול גם 
>   כן להתפלל ערבית מפלג המנחה כרבי יהודה

Translation: And the consensus of the Sages is: Mincha time is until evening [whereas others said it is only earlier], so the Gemara is only citing this to tell us one can also daven Ma`ariv from Pelag haMinchah onwards like Rabi Yehudah.